# Based on location How to change the banner image?

Tags: views

I am new to drupal 8 how to change banner image based on location. i created one content type in that two fileds i am added one is banner image and another one is location. while loading the page based on location how to change the banner

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Drupal Answers (and Drupal)...

First, some assumptions... by location you mean the region that the user is coming to your site.  E.g. some value from a module like Apache GEOIP or from a CloudFlare proxy front end.

Drupal uses a lot of caching for performance reasons.  AFAIK, there is no built in regional caching mechanism that will show different content based on some regional id.

We had the same sort of problem in trying to display the local support and sales numbers based on region.  Our solution was to have the numbers set via JavaScript.

The basic process was to have a URL that just returns the country code of the caller, e.g. /geoip/country.  This can just be a bit of php that looks for the server's environment variable with the country code (e.g. `$_SERVER['GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE']`) and returns this.

The Drupal JS makes an ajax call to get this, then uses it to determine the region and phone number to display.  Basically, a select statement with regional country codes.

For performance reasons, we also put the country code into a cookie and test if this is set before doing the ajax call.

This method lets Drupal and it's other caching front ends work to minimize load time while giving a regional display.